# Cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type '[UIViewController]?'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I have a function that returns NSArray as below

```
func papulateViewControllers() -> NSArray{

    let chatVC = ChatsVC(nibName:"ChatsVC", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let contactVC = ContactsVC(nibName:"ContactsVC", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let notificationVC = NotificationsVC(nibName:"NotificationsVC", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())

    let chatNav = UINavigationController()
    chatNav.viewControllers = [chatVC]

    let contactNav = UINavigationController()
    contactNav.viewControllers = [contactVC]

    let notifNav = UINavigationController()
    notifNav.viewControllers = [notificationVC]

    return [chatNav, contactNav, notifNav]
}//end papulateViewControllers
```

I'm calling this method like this

```
var tabs = UITabBarController()
tabs.viewControllers = papulateViewControllers() as [AnyObject]
```

But I'm getting this error
**Cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type '[UIViewController]?'**

Suggestion are required to fix this error, plus to optimize above function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `NSArray` in Swift, use native arrays. `NSArray`s don't have strong type inference as they gave you `AnyObject`s, Swift array instead holds only one type and have strong type inference.

As your function returns an an array of view controllers change its return type to `[UIViewController]`, and then you can assign its return value directly without the cast (`as [AnyObject]`).

```
func papulateViewControllers() -> [UIViewController] {
    //Leave code the same
}
```

and then use it as

```
var tabs = UITabBarController()
tabs.viewControllers = papulateViewControllers() // No cast required
```

Comment: That solves the problem. Thanks ... I missed the natives arrays point.

Comment: I have already marked it accepted. Thanks for quick help, and reminding about forgotten concept.